# What is the best ease curve and speed for color transitions?

Tags: color, desktop-application, animation

I am creating a desktop app, and I'm currently implementing animations.

I understand from Material Design Guidelines that I should set the speed for transitions for desktop apps at about 100-250 ms to keep it short. I also understand that the curve used depends on where the object animated is moving to and from.

But I could not find any resources on animating colors when hovering over or pressing an object (e.g. hovering over a button, hover over an item in a navigation drawer, hovering over a back button). In these examples, the color changes from the normal color to a shade or tint of the original.

What is the recommended duration for these kinds of animations (the buttons and objects are generally small)? Currently I am using 25-50ms for these color animations.

What is the recommended easing curve for these kinds of animations? Currently I am debating between EASE_OUT and EASE_BOTH.

Comment: I think it highly depends on where those color transitions and what those objects are. That would also determine the time and intensity of the transition. Do you have a specific example that we could look at so the answers here are all based on the same demo?

Comment: @Sir Exotic I realised it would be hard to give an example now so I will come back and ask again in a few months time, when I have a basic prototype working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once suggestion is use the inspect too to look at a few buttons on different websites to compare the timing and easing in them.

Normally for animation i'd follow the following

- When ui elements are entering the screen, use Ease-out animations
- For ui elements that are exiting, use Ease-in animations which are accelations

The case you mention can be a bit subjective. For color animation which are essentially state changes, you could consider using ease-in-out at around 300ms.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/the-basics-of-easing